# How can I "disable" require.js at runtime?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, amd

My team and I have an AngularJS app that *does not* use RequireJS but is loaded *within the context of an existing site* which uses RequireJS.  During the build process I am minifying/concatenating all our scripts into a single JS file which includes certain vendor libs like Lodash, Moment, etc.

Running the site isolated from the parent is fine, but within the context of the parent application I get the [well-documented error](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch):

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () { return _; }
```

I don't have control of the parent application, is there a way **at runtime** to "disable" RequireJS or configure it to ignore my scripts?

The current solution we have is to modify the vendor libs and remove the AMD code, but this is undesired because we use Bower (with [grunt-bower-install](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep)) and would like to just update dependencies automatically rather than rely on manual processes and custom hacks.

Comment: Are you doing the same concatenation & minification if you run the app isolated?

Comment: What's the stacktrace of that error? Is your parent site actually using a `define` function?

Comment: "Are you doing the same concatenation & minification if you run the app isolated?" Yes, it's the same process. I don't know what the parent site is doing, but I can replicate the problem simply by including RequireJS at the top of my Angular app.

Comment: Ah, so your angular app actually is supposed not to use require? I somehow thought it did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An approach that could be considered if you are confident you have all the relevant script dependencies under control is to hide the `define` function at the start of your minified/concatenated scripts.

For example, do something like the following at the start of the minified scripts:

```
var __origDefine = define;
define = null;
```

And at the end of the minified scripts:

```
define = __origDefine;
```

Comment: I tried this exact solution last night and so far it's working but I'm waiting for a deployment to the parent site to make sure. I was going to answer my own question but if this works I'll accept your answer, cheers!